# HTML5 Navigation

Tags: css, html

I have coded the HTML & CSS below. I am having problems with the positioning the **nav** on the right of the page. Any help is much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<header>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
    <nav>
       <a href='#'>Projects</a>
       <a href='#'>Pages</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  color: #333;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

nav a {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

**Desired Outcome**
[image]

Comment: Hmm...your desired outcome looks like the jsfiddle I made with your code. http://jsfiddle.net/DVnDw/ How does it appear on your website?

Comment: @SirDerpington Is all my CSS code necessary?

Comment: Is it in a particular browser this issue? What might be happening is a browser like IE8 (or older) which doesn't handle the HTML5 tags well without something like [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Comment: @SusanRobinson That depends on your aim how you want it to look :D At frist glance I see nothing that is totally unnecessary.. But I'm confused because you opened other questions with similar HTML & CSS Code

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you think that `nav` isn't completely positioned to the right, it could be that it **just seems so** because of the right margin you give each `a` element. Then, the last one will be always 30 pixels from the right. So, `nav` is really on the right, it's just the `a` margin that is not.

You can avoid this by doing this:

```
nav a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

I think the code need no explanation.